# SpringMVC: How to filter the client's IP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I use the `spring-boot`, and I have a `@Controller`. For security, I want to only accept `127.0.0.1`'s request (`@RequestMapping`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1.

Since you are using spring-boot, I assume you'll prefer to use Spring's auto configuration classes.Use a  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and configure your access rules there.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeUrls()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/24')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

      }
    }
```

---

### Option 2

If you are using **tomcat**, you can customize Tomcat’s proxy configuration on your application.properties. Reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server).

`server.tomcat.internal-proxies=192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}`

Comment: your answer is better

Answer (score 3):

you can do this is to use Spring Security's [Web Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-access-web). For example:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*"
        access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/24')"/>
    ...
</http>
```